# How to modify `request.params.id` type with declaration merging in Typescript/Express?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typescript-typings

I've successfully added `currentUser` to Express' `Request` interface:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      currentUser?: User;
    }
  }
}
```

However, I also want to specify that the Request's path param `req.params.id` (where `req` is of type `Express.Request`) is a Number and not a String (which is the default type of params from the Request interface). But I'm not sure how to do this as it is nested inside of the ParamsDictionary interface. Here's a snippet of what I tried **unsuccessfully**:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface ParamsDictionary extends Request {
      id: number;
    }
  }
}
```

For reference, `Request` is defined like this in the default Express/Typescript config file:

```
interface Request<
        P = core.ParamsDictionary,
        ResBody = any,
        ReqBody = any,
        ReqQuery = core.Query,
        Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
    > extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals> {}
```

This is why I've been trying to modify the ParamsDictionary, which I assume contains the path params that can be found in `req.params` of a middleware or route function.
I still get errors such as this one, which proves that Typescript still assumes that the `id` is a string (which I confirm it isn't. it is passed as number): [image]